# DbConttext.Set<Type>().Add(), The entity type User is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Ive been searching for a while regarding a problem I'm having. Basically, I'm developing a simple application that really doesn't need the full EF setup.

What I'd like to do is use the DbContext class to query/insert/update data directly. I can query data using the SqlQuery method, but Im having problems inserting an entity.

So here my code,

User.cs : entity

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace StkManagement.Models
{
    [Table("Users")]
    public class User
    {

        public string UserName
        {
            set;
            get;
        }

        public string Password
        {
            set;
            get;
        }
    }
}

//user is an instance
DbContext.Set[type]().Add(user);
```

I cant add angle brakets in the code, not sure how to do this.

The code above throws an exception, "The entity type User is not part of the model for the current context.", Ive searched around but it seems there could be several reasons for the message. If anyone can share some light into this, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: If you're using Code First, have you added your model to your data context? SqlQuery is direct SQL access without touching the objects you've setup.

Comment: Hi Steve, I understand SqlQuery is direct access which is intened. With regards to adding the model to the data context,do you mean   DbContext.Set[User]().Attach(user);   , is so then I have done that.

Comment: Hmm... you may want to read something on the DbContext because I have a feeling you haven't derived from it to include your models. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx

Comment: Can you show the class that you derived from DbContext that has Users as a DbSet?

Comment: Hi, thanks for all your comments I haven't derived for the db context class. So I guess what your saying in order to insert I have to do this?